# TSP version connection to MST.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Hi I'm interested in the connection of the minimum spanning tree problem to the traveling salesman problem. My version of TSP is a fully connected graph with positive integer weights that does not satisfy the triangle inequality. I did a little test of trying to predict through regression models TSP runtime using MST features and gained a nice accuracy, but I can't figure out the connection. Any suggestions?